# For loop inside for loop giving strange results

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I have a program where I have a for loop inside a for loop.  What I get as result in the last array.push is that the Albumtitle is always the last result of the first for loop.  When I loop into the chrome console then I see that the first for loop delivers for example 3 results before I see even it getting into the second for loop.  Am I using for loops incorrectly or is there an issue in the code?

```
 selected_artist(id){

  this.musicservice.get_artist_albums(id).subscribe(payload => { 
      this.tracks_to_play=[];
      this.albums=[]=payload.MediaContainer.Metadata;
      this.test=[];
        for (this.i_albums=0; this.i_albums<this.albums.length; ++this.i_albums) {
          this.albumtitle=this.albums[this.i_albums].title;
          this.musicservice.get_artist_albums(this.albums[this.i_albums].key).subscribe(tracks_data => { 
            this.tracks=tracks_data.MediaContainer.Metadata;
            this.art=tracks_data.MediaContainer.thumb;
              for (this.i_tracks=0; this.i_tracks<this.tracks.length; ++this.i_tracks) {
                this.tracks_to_play.push({Key: this.tracks[this.i_tracks].Media[0].Part[0].file,  Title: this.tracks[this.i_tracks].title,  Duration: this.tracks[this.i_tracks].Media[0].Part[0].duration}); 
                }
            this.test.push({AlbumTitle : this.albumtitle, Tracks: this.tracks_to_play })
            this.tracks_to_play=[];
            console.log(this.test);
      this.album_selected=true; 
      this.album_selected=true; 
});
     }
});

}
```

Comment: could you please make a stackblitz example

Comment: A correct indentation can save hours of debugging